# Facing error in mysqli with php

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, fetch

I am trying to get data form table using where condition. here is my code to It return me only one value. Before this logic i used foreach function but it gives me same one value.

```
 public function text1(){

        $valuee = array('20','14','9');
        $length = count($valuee);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE id = '".$valuee[$i]."'";
            $rs = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->link));
             return $rs;
            }

    }
```

Here is rsult :

```
mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 6 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )
```

Comment: this is the normal behaviour of mysqli_query :)

Comment: read more about [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) function and what should you do after that

Answer (score 2):

Two main problems:

First, you `return $rs;` inside your loop. *In the first iteration of your loop, this return will immediately end your function and return the value.* You need to collect the results in an array inside the loop, and return that array of results *after* the loop.

Second, you are executing a query with `mysqli_query`, but you aren't fetching any rows from the result object it returns.

```
public function text1(){
    $valuee = array('20','14','9');
    $length = count($valuee);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE id = '".$valuee[$i]."'";
        $rs = mysqli_query($this->link, $sql) or die(mysqli_error($this->link));

        // fetch the row from the result into an array
        $results[] = $rs->fetch_assoc();
    }

    // return the array after it has been filled in the loop
    return $results;
}
```

There are a couple of other issues, but this is the main logic error that's giving you trouble right now.

Comment: why not selecting `where in`, instead of looping over an array

Comment: @hassan I thought about it, but decided against it, mostly because of those "other issues" I mentioned. I think this should really be a prepared statement, and prepared statements are kind of a pain in mysqli, especially for WHERE IN with an arbitrary number of parameters. I decided to just explain why the way they were doing it wasn't working instead.